# How to add code after "</article>" in content-page.php in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

I am using the Shareaholic plugin and they give you a block of code to add the sharing buttons anywhere on your site.

```
    [shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="7726121"]
    [shareaholic app="recommendations" id="7962129"]
```

I want to add this code after `</article>` tag in the file "content-page.php" in Wordpress. When I do it then nothing happens. When I check the page source then I can't find the code anywhere. It happens even when I add some random word after `</article>` tag.

How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Try closing the shortcodes. `[shortcode][/shortcode]`. In your case try Ram Sharmas solution but like this `echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="7726121"][/shareaholic]');`

Comment: I tired this way also but the result remains the same :(

Answer (score 1):

These are short code and you can't call them directly you need to do it like this.

```
echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="7726121"]');
echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="recommendations" id="7962129"]');
```

Comment: I get the same, nothing.